# Mongoose specify optional array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

One of the keys in my mongo collection is

```
    options: [
      new mongoose.Schema(
        {
          answer: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
          },
          value: {
            type: Number,
            min: -10,
            max: 10,
            required: true,
          },
        },
        { _id: false }
      ),
    ],
```

The issue I'm having here is that `options` is optional but when there's no options field filled out, the inserted document has `options: []`

I believe I'm able to solve this normally by putting a `default: undefined` but I'm not sure how to go about doing this for this array of objects.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In mongoose an empty array is a default value for an array type. You can override it by using `default` field this way:

```
let optionsSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        answer: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        value: {
            type: Number,
            min: -10,
            max: 10,
            required: true,
        },
    },
    { _id: false });


const RootSchema = new Schema({
    options : {
        type: [optionsSchema],
        default: undefined
    }
})
```

Comment: You're awesome!!

Comment: Just bear in mind that using an update query with: `$push`, `$addToSet` , or `$pull` won't be possible with an undefined array, so you should check it. I guess this is the reason the array is empty by default.